# How to check whether the keyboard is shown or not?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, earlgrey

I'm using `EarlGrey`for automated UI testing on an iOS project. I want to check whether the keyboard is shown or not after swiping away on the screen.

I've seen the header file in `EarlGrey` framework named [GREYKeyboard.h](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/EarlGrey/Core/GREYKeyboard.h) with a function named `isKeyboardShown` with a bool return value. This would be very helpful for me, but I don't know how to use it since I have no access to this API.

`EarlGrey` is installed with `Carthage`.

Comment: Why do you not subscribe the notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. You can access to `GREYKeyboard.h` (which is a private header) by editing the `module.modulemap` file. Add the

`header "../PrivateHeaders/GREYKeyboard.h"`

line to the file. The `module.modulemap` file should look like this after editing:

```
 framework module EarlGrey {
  umbrella header "EarlGrey.h"

  header "../PrivateHeaders/GREYKeyboard.h"
  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You include the `GREYKeyboard.h` header and do this:

```
if (GREYKeyboard.isKeyboardShown) {
    ; // the keyboard is showing
}
else {
    ; // it's not
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me more information on how to include the GREYKeyboard. h header?

Comment: @S.Boy do you have `import EarlGrey` at the top of your swift file?

Comment: Of course, but I still do not have access to GREYKeyboard, but for example I have access to GREYInteractions. I think I have to add the GREYKeyboard header extra, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: add `#import <EarlGrey/GREYKeyboard.h>` before [this line](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/931aa8c6edf2f6cfb1ccf76adcbadf6621bc5711/EarlGrey/EarlGrey.h#L57)

Comment: GREYKeyboard is private so you shouldn't just import it directly. Remember, with EarlGrey you can also check for the existence of individual keyboard keys as well, such as grey_text(@"Return").

Comment: Unfortunately the #import <EarlGrey/GREYKeyboard.h>  didn't work. I've already developed a workaround, but I really want to use the GREYKeyboard. Can I have access to it despite it's a private header?